# Bluetooth speaker: preferred mode "High fidelity playback" (A2DP) is not getting saved

Tags: unity, 13.04, sound, bluetooth, speakers

**UPDATE Aug 2017: The solution marked as accepted by me apppears to have worked until Ubuntu 15.10. For 16.04+ choose one of the more recent solutions.**

**For 16.04+ the config file is `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` NOT /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf .**

I have a bluetooth speaker, Sony SRS-BTX300, which works in linux/ubuntu 13.04, but only after some fiddling. (Update Dec 2013: same problems remain in 13.10)

I have to set the preferred bandwidth mode to "High fidelity playback" (A2DP) each time after switching on the computer and reconnecting the speaker.

The mode resets itself to "telephony/duplex" (=low bandwidth) every time. It takes about 20 clicks to reset the speaker, (click through menu, disconnect, reconnects, select mode, test), and these are definitely too many clicks.

How can I make "A2DP" mode the default mode, an do so in a persistent manner?

A few screen shots will illustrate.

After choosing this menu by clicking on the bluetooth icon in the top panel in  Unity...

[image: Bluetooth Icon on panel]

After setting up this...

[image: A2DP]

... the preferred mode will be reset to this after restarting/suspending the computer

[image: Telephony Duplex]

Comment: You may try playing with the settings in the `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file. E.g. if you don't use any headset, change the `MaxConnected=1` setting to `0`.

Comment: @falconer This worked on 15.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's an option in `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` called a`AutoConnect=true`which is hashed out.

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
```

Delete the "#" at the start of the AutoConnect=true line

I found enabling this option by removing the `#` and got things connecting properly with my bluetooth headset

Restart the bluetooth service for the change to take effect:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: Thanks! - in that config file, the  comment text above that option was quite verbose, and a bit misleading (*"so the default setting of true is usually a good idea."* and it's *commented out*: `#AutoConnect=true`. --- Removal of the "#" now also seems to work for me, although I haven't rebooted yes (just switched speaker on and off)

Comment: First it worked, but now it doesn't anymore. More ideas?

Comment: No such file in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: Same as @tim and adding the file didn't help.

Comment: Why does this not have *all* the upvotes?

Comment: no such file in 16.04 either...

Comment: This worked for my new Bose Quiet Control 30 headphones/neckbuds (QC30). It sounded pretty hissy and was driving me crazy, now it sounds like something I expect from Bose!

Comment: As of Ubuntu 17.04, no such file either. I tried to modify `main.conf` instead, adding `AutoConnect=true` someplace in the file, but it didn't solve my problem...

Comment: @JohannesLemonde - uncommenting `Name = BlueZ` in that file and restarting bluetooth solved it for me in Xfce (18.04): https://askubuntu.com/a/1087118/925128

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 19.04, though I had to re-pair my headset (Sony 700N)

Comment: The configuration in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf didn't work for me. Every time my headphones or laptop go off and on again the automatically reconnected headphones go into 'HSP/HFP' and they can not be set to 'A2DP Sink'. They require to reconnect/repair. So I scripted it into this gist: https://gist.github.com/egelev/2e6b57d5a8ba62cf6df6fff2878c3fd4

Comment: @knb It is commented out, because `true` is the default, built-in setting.

Answer (score 29):

Add the following line to `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`:

```
[General]
Disable=Headset
```

and then run this command:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

[Thread: (Natty) Connect only A2DP profile for bluetooth headset.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1761433)

Comment: Unbelievably enough, this worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Uh, don't forget to **`sudo restart bluetooth`** for the setting to take effect.

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 with Upstart: `sudo restart --system bluetooth`

Comment: Not effective in 15.10. :(

Comment: if I do  then the speaker no longer appears in sound settings. how could I debug it ?

Comment: Works for ubuntu 16.04, but the file is `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Comment: This was the other half of the puzzle for getting Bose Quiet Control 30 neckbuds/headphones (QC30) to work for me in Ubuntu 14.04. 

The other half is the other answer in this question. http://askubuntu.com/a/563996/11929

Comment: Yes! works for ubuntu 16.04 --> /etc/bluetooth/main.conf.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04
I have just added `Disable=Headset` in the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and restarted the bluetooth service with `sudo service bluetooth restart`

Comment: I tried this in 18.04 and get this error on `service bluetooth status`: `Unknown key Disable for group General in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Comment: Worked for me adding this line to main.conf, Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 12):

For those wondering, I found in Ubuntu 16.04 there is a slight difference to the answer:

```
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

And update the following line

```
#AutoEnable=false
```

to

```
AutoEnable=true
```

Followed by

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

For me, this defaulted the audio profile to A2DP Sink when connecting a bluetooth audio device.

Comment: works, but I also added `Disable=Headset` and restarted my computer

Comment: Dunno what you mean @cipricus.  I added Disable=Headset to my /etc/bluetooth/main.conf file I think.

Comment: @wordsforthewise - I wanted to find if both lines are needed or, if only one is enough, whether both work. - Trying to test, I find that in fact I had both. Commenting `Disable=Headset` & restarting bluetooth, all is fine. Commenting *also* `AutoEnable=true` & restarting bluetooth: cannot connect the headset. But after restarting the system I can connect it, and all is fine although both lines are commented now. Odd.

Comment: Just because this worked for you by coincidence, doesn't mean it is a solution. `AutoEnable` does nothing else but enable the adapter on boot.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Gnome3 and after some time my headset no longer connected at A2DP again. I had to stop Gnome creating a pulseaudio daemon by creating the file `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/client.conf` (as root) and adding the following lines to it:

```
autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true
```

Then set the owner to gdm:

```
sudo chown gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/client.conf
```

Then log off/on or look for the pulseaudio process running as the `gdm` user with `ps aux | grep pulse`

(Trimmed) output looks like:

```
gdm       2943  10616 ?        S<l  Sep01   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio..
```

Then kill the process with `kill <pid>` which for me was `2943`

Running `bluetoothctl` and connecting again, I could then run `pacmd list-cards` and find my device `index: 2` and change to the a2dp_sink with `pacmd set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink`.

Finally working again!

Answer (score 2):

In order to auto switch audio into A2DP bluetooth device when connected in Ubuntu 14.04 I followed the instructions from https://sandalov.org/blog/2146/ and it worked perfectly.

Modify `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to automatically switch pulseaudio sink to Bluez:

```
.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-switch-on-connect  # Add this
.endif
```

Modify `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` to auto select A2DP profile (instead of HSP/HFP):

```
[General]
Disable=Headset # Add this
```

Apply changes:

```
pulseaudio -k # Restarts pulseaudio
sudo service bluetooth restart # Restarts BT
```

*More info at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset*

Comment: Not working for 16.04. This answer disables all audio output sources (creates a fault in PulseAudio).

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 19.10 with my Sony Headset WH-1000XM3. (Except that I put the changes for `audio.conf` in `main.conf` under `[Policy]`)

Comment: Btw, it did look like it disabled the audio at first, but then it came back after a bit. Restarting could probably help.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is, that the default configuration allows only one profile per device. This can be changed by setting `MultiProfile` to `single` or `multiple` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. Restart the bluetooth daemon afterwards. You will then be able to change the profile on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Ubuntu 22.04

Edit `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Uncomment or add

**MultiProfile = off**

Restart bluetooth service

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Then you will be able to change output device configuration from Settings > Sound