# 14.04 Bluetooth Speaker Automatically Switches from A2DP to Telephony Duplex

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth speaker, I originally paired it with my Ubuntu 14.04 machine and mistakenly had the curiosity to see if I could change equalizer settings by installing `pulseaudio-equalizer`. When I did that and performed a restart, I could no longer set the speakers mode to **High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)**. The option was listed, but it wasn't applying the setting.

I decided to re-pair the bluetooth speaker, and when I did I was able to set the mode to **High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)**. But, it doesn't keep that setting. So now, ever since I installed and sequentially removed pulseaudi-equalizer, I have to re-pair the device after every reboot to apply the **High Fidelity Playback (A2DP)** mode.

Is there a configuration issue that I am missing? A library missing? Do I have a profile that my configuration is defaulting to on reboot?

I should also note that when I uninstalled `pulseaudio-equalizer` it ended up breaking my audio sound indicator and removing sound systems from system settings. I had to reinstall both to get them to appear again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much!

Comment: did you try that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/319871/bluetooth-speaker-preferred-mode-high-fidelity-playback-a2dp-is-not-getting?rq=1