# Bluetooth Headset: Can't set A2DP (High Fidelity Playback). Poor sound quality

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headset

I'm trying to use my bluetooth headset (Bluedio, in the screenshot) in Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10, but I keep getting a horrible sound quality in everything.

Important note: I've just tested with a different device, a bluetooth **speaker**, and it gets the A2DP profile automatically, with a nice sound quality. The problem, then, is only happening with my bluetooth **headset**.

I've read some posts and the given suggestions don't work in my case (Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10). These suggestions are:

1) Under the Sound settings, change the headset profile to the A2DP (High Fidelity Playback). Not only the sound quality didn't even change, the profile keeps getting turned back to Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) profile, in which the sound quality remains horrible. So, even though the A2DP profile shows up there, it doesn't take effect and goes back to the HSP/HFP profile everytime.

2) Changes in the /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf file, like uncommenting the line "AutoConnect=true line". First of all, there isn't such file in Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10. Instead, there is the /etc/bluetooth/main.conf file, which seems pretty similar to the first one in terms of parameters. But, the line is already uncommented in my S.O., just as the suggestion tells me to do. So, it seems that there's nothing to do here with this suggestion.

Here's the screenshot of the Sound Settings' screen. You can see that there's an arrow for the dropdown list, where the A2DP profile shows up (even though it's not appearing in the shot. It's there though), but it gets back to the HSP/HFP profile everytime.

Here's the link for the screenshot:

[image: picture 1]

Comment: See this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/319871/427334).

Comment: sometimes you might forgot about the output volume when selecting `High fidelity playback`

Comment: Is there a bug being tracked for this somewhere?

Answer (score 51):

I've managed to fix it. Even though I'm not sure if the following steps are in the exactly order to do it, I'm pretty sure it was the combination of them that fixed it. Here they are:

1. I've installed Blueman: `sudo apt install blueman`
2. I've edited the `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` file: `sudo -H gedit /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` and added this line in the end of it: `Disable=Headset`. Users on Ubuntu 17.04 and above may not have `audio.conf`, but can instead use `main.conf`.

Note: I've also installed something called `pavucontrol` from the terminal with the command `sudo apt install pavucontrol`, but I'm really not sure if it was this or the Blueman that solved it. I suspect it was the Blueman, but if it doesn't help, try the pavucontrol and see if it solves it.

Don't forget to restart the bluetooth service after the change with `sudo systemctl start bluetooth`

Comment: Yeah, adding that line `Disable=Headset` did it for me. :D And *pavucontrol* is PulseAudio Volume Control, so I don't think installing that was necessary to fix the problem.

Comment: I have just tested the step 1 and 2. Re-connected the bluetooth headset and it worked for me. So no need for pavucontrol.

Comment: Here Here!!  Worked for me too.  Only needed blueman on Ubuntu 17.04.  Then I edited main.conf and restarted bluetooth from the top panel icon.  After that I selected high fidelity and now it works.  Nice writeup - Thanks!

Comment: `Disable=Headset` worked for me, but I also had to do `sudo service bluetooth restart` for it to work. And the question remains: _Why does it work?_

Comment: testing in 18.04-based system: `blueman` is **not needed**, no more than `pavucontrol`; the decisive setting is the `Disable=Headset` line (in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`). In `pavucontrol`: only after adding that line, the "High Fidelity Playback" setting becomes available (after restart). Another solution that I haven't yet tested: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/952148/925128).

Comment: To clarify: after doing this, will I still be able to use the headset as, well, a headset? I'm asking because I see three audio profiles in pavucontrol and blueman-applet: headset, high-fidelity sink, high-fidelity source. Selecting high-fidelity sink in pavucontrol (the default in 18.04) results in no audio source from the headset appearing at all.

Comment: Not working for in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It's not working for me with ubuntu 18.04. I edited the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and added the line at the end of it, restarted the `bluetooth` service, even restarted my computer but when I select my headset as Output + Input (mic) it automatically switches the profile to HSP/HPF. Moreover, in pavucontrol, If the A2DP profile is selected, I can't see my headset in the input peripherals tab. Any idea?

Comment: I seem to have to run `sudo service bluetooth restart` after any reboots

Comment: Nothing worked for me on this whole page until I installed pavucontrol -> configuration -> and changed the bluetooth device to A2DP and the codec to SBC

Answer (score 33):

1. Install Blueman:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install blueman
   ```
2. Add `Disable=headset` to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.
3. Restart the bluetooth daemon:

   ```
   sudo service bluetooth restart
   ```

If you still have poor sound quality go to `pavucontrol` and under *Configuration* set the profile of your device to off and then to A2DP and it should work now.

Comment: Works like a charm in Linux Mint 19! Thanks :)

Comment: Worked for Arch Linux in 2020!

Comment: Does not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: That worked for me on Elementary OS(Ubuntu 18.04). Took just 2 minutes to do. Thanks lot. Earlier my ANC headphones were giving too much noise due to mic and poor audio quality. Its crystal clear now.

Comment: @AjithMemana glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Worked for me in unbuntu 20.04, many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem with automatic change back to HSP/HFP.

I solved this by editing `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and uncommenting the line

```
Name = BlueZ
```

in the section `[General]`.

Though, it might be not available, when the `bluez` package is not installed.

Thanks anyway for the tip with the file.

Comment: I had to uncomment this line as well to get mine to work.  Thanks.

Comment: worked in 18.04

Comment: I first thought this fixed it, but unfortunately every time I reconnect, the headphones are back on HSP/HFP instead of A2DP. :(

Comment: Worked on Manjaro. I'm very confused though because I would have guessed the name would have no effect on actual behavior.

Answer (score 8):

Get the index of your card:

```
pacmd list-cards
```

Set the cards profile to a2dp (example: index 2):

```
pacmd set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink
```

Credit to `develmusa` of the ArchLinux forums:  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1720877#p1720877

Comment: This gives me "Failed to set card profile", which seems to be a common issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/765233/pulseaudio-fails-to-set-card-profile-to-a2dp-sink-how-can-i-see-the-logs-and

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that works for me is to restart the bluetooth service and reconnect.

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Worked also on Mint 19.2

Comment: All that was needed for Pop!_OS 20.04

Answer (score 4):

I had to do the following for my Bluetooth headset to work, after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio --start    
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Not sure if it was a transient problem or not. Hope it won't happen again.

I got the following error in the logs when trying to enable the BT connection to the headphones, before doing the fix:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog 
.
.
Aug 23 15:01:33 my-p1gen2 bluetoothd[226778]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX: Protocol not available
```

After the fix, it worked.

Comment: Solved mine as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution for Ubuntu 20.10 w/Soundpeats TrueCapsule headphone/headset.

**1. Enable MultiProfile support /etc/bluetooth/main.conf**

On/near line 58, you'll see `#MultiProfile = off`. Uncomment (or add a new line) with `MultiProfile = multiple`.

**2. Remove the bluetooth device and re-add it.**

This is important. Switching to A2DP did not work for me until I dropped and re-added.

[image]

**3. Switch to A2DP.**

Click Sound Settings (see above screenshot) and select A2DP.  You should be able to switch back and forth on the fly (with noticeable sound quality differences).

**Note:** When I enable the headset microphone, output switches to HSP.  I don't know whether this is a necessity of the bluetooth A2DP and HSP codecs, or merely a limitation of the bluetooth implementation. In any case, consider installing  [GNOME Sound Output Device Chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/), which makes it easy to switch between profiles. [image]

Comment: Is it possible to enable 2-side A2DP?
For me it works only as input or output, but not both.
2-side it works only for HSP/HFP

Comment: I don't know the answer to that specifically, but I can tell you that I use my headsets to listen to music and for zoom calls without manually changing the profile.

Comment: @AndreyP, no. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2819/how-do-i-send-bluetooth-audio-from-the-stereo-a2dp-to-headset-hsp-profile

So either use A2DP without microphone, or HSP/HFP (much worse sound quality) with a mic.

Comment: I'm trying to connect airdots 3 pro via bluetooth to my Ubuntu 20.04, but it always reconnect them as HSP / HPF, needing me to manually change to A2DP. Is there a way to remember it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the info, worked great!

On Ubuntu 17.10 I had to change:

Settings > sound > output tab
Select Bluetooth output
Then set profile to 'high fidelity playback (a2dp sink)

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me
https://askubuntu.com/a/1186839/834728

```bsh
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
killall pulseaudio
```

Try to connect again.